# C# get or set cookies, to download content from the web using cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, setcookie

I need help with cookies. I'm planing use cookies to download web content. To get the content I need to log into a website because only authorized users can download web content or files. I'm using

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

and then I'm scraping source code, and I need to get link to file, but I can't get because I'm not authorized, so I need to set cookies. I have not worked with cookies before.
How do I to do this?

Comment: Since you say you solved it then you should post the answer you've used or select the answer you found that solves it so that other people can benefit.

Answer (score 7):

If you are talking about creating a asp.net web app that can create cookies, then doing this should work:

Not sure if this would work in asp.net mvc though, this works in asp.net web forms

```
Response.Cookies["nameOfCookie"].Value = "someValue";
Response.Cookies["nameOfCookies].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

then on a post back on say same page or different page, can get cookie by

```
string value = string.Empty;
if (Request.Cookies["nameOfCookie"] != null)    
    value = Request.Cookies["nameOfCookie"].Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created a quick little application that helps with generating web requests for me

```
public class HttpRequestHandler {
    private CookieContainer cookies;

    public HttpRequestHandler() {
        cookies = new CookieContainer();
    }

    public HttpWebRequest GenerateWebRequest(string url) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(url));

        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Referer = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(referer);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
        request.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        request.Timeout = 40000;

        return request;
    }
}
```

Your problem is probably related to lack of a CookieContainer. If you create a cookie container you can save/use cookies in your web requests.

Comment: Thank you.In web page from browser i can see in head JavaScript and there are in two places first:function SetCookie(name, value, days){
expires = new Date(today.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);So i need set in container 3 values: name, value, days.What will be code look like?

Comment: Thank you all for time and for effort.Solved

Answer (score 1):

You should set the [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) property of the HTTPWebRequest class to an instance of a [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx) class. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx), it's stated that:

> CookieContainer is null by default. You must assign a CookieContainer object to the property to have cookies returned in the Cookies property of the HttpWebResponse returned by the GetResponse method.

In other words, after you have set the *CookieContainer* property of the HTTPWebRequest object in your code, you can get the corresponding *Cookies* in the HTTPWebResponse object in your code. The sample code in the MSDN link shared above should get you started.

Answer (score -2):

Could you be more speciffic about the project? is it a Desktop Application, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC?

in ASP.NET MVC I used SetPersistenCookie method every time when user is logging in, and for methods I use Authorize Attribute, every time when a user wants to acces somenthig and he is not logged in it redirects him to LogIn page...

Comment: It's for C# windows forms...

Little about project:Scraping from web source code using c#, cutting source code example:links, content,photos,data.
When I'm trying to get source code I'm getting source code that I don't need. That is way I need to set cookies to get right source code that i need.Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for time and for effort.Solved